# How to make span not disappear when hovering over image?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images with a span over each. At the moment, I have the hover effect applied to just the image, but the span content disappears when its hovered over. I've tried applying the hover effect to the li element instead, and the span didn't disappear, but I don't want the hover effect to be applied to the span. `pointer-events: none` hasn't worked.

```css
li>a img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  top: 45%;
  left: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'OstrichSans Regular';
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<li key={index}>
  <span>{set.set_name}</span>
  <a href="./sets/[slug]"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt={set.set_name}/></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `span` a positive [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) value.

```css
li > a img:hover{
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li span{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  top: 45%;
  left: 15%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'OstrichSans Regular';
  font-size: large;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<li key={index}>
    <span>{set.set_name}</span>
    <a href="./sets/[slug]"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" .url()} alt={set.set_name}/></a>
</li>
```

Comment: You're right that it prevents it from disappearing (thanks for introducing me to the z-index btw), but it has the same issue that I'm trying to avoid by not applying the hover effect to the overall <li>, being that the hover effect is still applied to the span. Do you know how I can make it so that it doesn't apply to the span element?

Comment: @paparonnie I don't see where the `hover` effect is affecting the `li` nor the `span`, only on the `img` as indicated in the CSS.

Comment: @paparonnie this do it for you?